# Record does not exist or has been deleted. Odoo 14

Tags: javascript, python, xml, odoo

I added buttons in lines on  wizard of payment. (pos module)
When clicking on button, I want to delete the payment, but I got this error:

```
"Record does not exist or has been deleted .
 (Record: pos.payment(100,), User: 2) "
```

What's wrong please ? Any help?

```
class PosPayment(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'pos.payment'

    def delete_payment(self):
        self.unlink()
        return {
            'context': self.env.context,
            'view_type': 'form',
            'view_mode': 'form',
            'res_model': 'pos.make.payment',
            'res_id': self.id,
            'view_id': False,
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'target': 'new',
        }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please show your xml code @K.ju

Comment: Hm, you delete (unlink) `self` and just work with it later `self.id`. What do you expect to happen? ;-)

Comment: You probably want to use the wizard's ID on the return. `self.id` is not the wizard's ID.

Comment: @CZoellner, yes I want to use the wizard id , but even I remove the block of return wizard , I got always same error.

Comment: In xml code, I added the payment_ids tree in pos.make.payment model. @Saks_here

Comment: Where did you add your button in wizard? Which model did you inherit in xml? @K.ju

Comment: I herited the model 'pos.make.payment'  in xml , to add buttons in 'view_pos_payment' view.  @Saks_here

Comment: @K.ju i guess you tried the wrong model. Wizard has different model when look at this in debug mode. It may have like "invite.wizard". When wizard is opened you could see a bug picture at the top of it. When you click it, there you could see a debug view. Kindly check it out.

Comment: But , I added the buttons on 'payment_ids' which is in 'pos.payment' model; like this : <field name="model">pos.make.payment</field>
 <field name="inherit_id" ref="point_of_sale.view_pos_payment"/>
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
 <xpath expr="....>
   <field name="payment_ids" nolabel="1" readonly="1">
     <tree string="Payments" editable="bottom">
                           ...
          <field name="amount"/>
         <button name="delete_payment" type="object" icon="fa-trash"/>
         </tree>....@Saks_here

Comment: @K.ju so you created a button in tree view. While you click on the button, it does not delete the record. Right!? You may try type="action" instead of type="object"